# Uniqueness problem in measures on $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

> **Defintion:**
>   Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of subsets of a set $X$. A set function $\mu:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ is said to be $\sigma$-finite if $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ where $X_n\in\mathcal{C}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are pairwise disjoint sets such that $\mu(X_n)<\infty$ for every $n$.
>
> **Theorem** $1:$
>   Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a semi-algebra of subsets of a set $X$ and $\mathcal{S(C)}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. Let  $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be finitely additive set functions on $\mathcal{S(C)}$ such that $\mu_1(E)=\mu_2(E)$ for all $E\in\mathcal{C}$. Then, $\mu_1(E)=\mu_2(E)$ for all $E\in\mathcal{A(C)}$, where $\mathcal{A(C)}$ is the algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$.
>
> **Theorem** $2:$
>   Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a semi-algebra of subsets of a set $X$ and $\mathcal{S(C)}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. Let  $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be $\sigma$-finite measures on $\mathcal{S(C)}$ such that $\mu_1(E)=\mu_2(E)$ for all $E\in\mathcal{C}$. Then, $\mu_1(E)=\mu_2(E)$ for all $E\in\mathcal{S(C)}$.

Now, we have already proved the theorem $1$. But while proving Theorem $2$, my professor said that using the result of theorem $1$, we can assume that $\mu_1(E)=\mu_2(E)$ for all $E\in\mathcal{A(C)}$.

But I tried to clarify it, but he said to try home. But after a long-hours of spending time, I am unable to figure out *how does finite additivity of a set function implies that the set function is $\sigma$-finite*?

Can anyone please provide me some hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does finite additivity of a set function implies that the set function is $\sigma$-finite?

It doesn't.  There are plenty of examples of finitely additive set functions which are not $\sigma$-finite.  For instance, the set function $\mu$ defined by $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\mu(A) = \infty$ for all $A \ne \emptyset$.

But I don't think that is the statement you needed in the first place - you seem to have it backwards.  You are trying to prove Theorem 2, using Theorem 1.  So you suppose you have two $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$.  Measures are set functions which are countably additive, and in particular finitely additive, so they satisfy all the hypotheses of Theorem 1.  Therefore you may apply Theorem 1 to conclude that we have $\mu_1(E) = \mu_2(E)$ for all $E = \mathcal{A}(\mathcal{C})$.  The fact that they also happen to be $\sigma$-finite is not even needed for this step.